# How to find links not in HTML

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome-devtools

I am new to coding and thought an easy first project would be to scrape the urls which the map on this opening page directs one to.

https://www.discoverboating.com/boat-registration

I have not been able to figure out how this map directs one to each states website. The urls are not included in the HTML.  I have read that this is often the case with java/ajax pages and searched all the sources with the chrome developer using "ctrl+shift+f" thinking I'd find some sort of table taging states to urls.  I have not found urls there. I also see that when clicking the map no http requests appear to go out when observing the network tab in the chrome developer, so I have not been able to figure out how to mimic GET requests associated with clicking the map.

I'd be grateful to someone who could help explain how to find the urls associated with each state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this does seem to be a JavaScript redirect, but all of the JavaScript on the page is obfuscated making it difficult to read. Although, using a Chrome extension called *Redirect Path*, I was able to figure out that when you click on a state (in this case Montana), it redirects you to a page like this: https://takemefishing.1clickoutdoors.com/OCOcontent/1d722fb510376c333d1d57091bdf7cc6/MT/20
then that page redirects you to the appropriate state's website using a `meta` tag. When searching the source code of the original page for that URL, I found a list of options under the drop down box that lists all of the URLs. The system is pretty simple actually. All it does it takes the URL i referenced above, and changes `MT` to the specific state's code.

I hope this makes sense. Let me know if you have any other questions!